# Using JS to change the URL of a div background image, but it links to the CSS style sheet not the image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use JavaScript to change the background-image property of a div to a different URL, writing a function to do so and calling the function with an onHover event. However, it does not function the way I would please and checking Firefox Developer Tools shows that the URL is actually to the style sheet I am using. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

**The HTML**

This is where I have called the function.

```
<img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

This is the div I am trying to edit.

```
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>
```

**The Javascript**

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById(image).style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
}
```

Comment: Your made a typo. `image` is a variable when it looks like you intended it to be a string literal. If you had looked in the console of your browser's developer tools you should have seen an error message to the effect that you are trying to access the `style` property of `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the `'` on `getElementById`

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
}
```

Your typo wasn't invalid but it looked for the content of your `image` variable. Like:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    // Identical result using a variable
    let image_id = 'image'; 
    document.getElementById(image_id).style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
}
```

Comment: Don't know ? :(

Comment: Alas, it had to be something that simple. Those things can slip by so easily! Thanks!

Comment: @JacquesMarais I think he didn't add code formatting and that's why people might have downvoted, just for the sake of editing/review milestones.

Comment: Yeap, I used triple ` for bloc code but it didn't work here.